# Does posting my computer name publicly make my system vulnerable?

Tags: command-line, networking, security, naming

I am wondering if it is paranoia and/or privacy overkill to block out one's computer name when posting terminal output in public forums? I don't know enough about networking to know if it's possible that this information could make one's system vulnerable somehow (though I suspect not?) and was hoping someone could shed some light.

Comment: This question is more suitable for security.stackexchange.com than  AskUbuntu , I suggest you ask there

Comment: Moved to: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121316/does-posting-my-computer-name-publicly-make-my-system-vulnerable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your privacy concerns...

Your username and hostname could be used by someone who cracked your wifi as a "hint" to access your samba/netatalk shares. It can reveal some info about you depending on how you named the host and your username...

But these are not a system vulnerability, but a privacy concern. I, personally, change my hostname and use non-identifier username... just in case.